# Get property of DOM element the Angular 2 way

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to get the width of a DOM element in pixles.

jQuery way...

```
var myWidth = $('.labels').width();
```

It looks like I need to get a hold of the [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) from within a `@Component` or `Service` and access the `width` property.

It also says that aside from security reasons, it can couple the app and the rendering layers therefore preventing future deployment to a web worker.

So what is the best way to access that div width? I am working with an image that fills its div horizontally. I am overlaying some elements and I make the calculation `myHeight = aspectRatio * myWidth;`

All of the related questions I see mention how to do it back while Angular2 was still in the release candidate stage. So many API changes in the stable release (a month and 4 days as of today) that I feel like some sort of `#deprecated` tag would be helpful.

Comment: Please make sure that you have looked at all the relevant CSS properties, such as `object-fit`. Chances are good that they can solve your problem and save you from having to do manual calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Angular itself doesn't provide anything to read from the DOM.
If you want to read from the DOM you need to use `ElementRef`.
Using `ElementRef` is far less of a security concern than for example using jQuery.
It's correct that you prevent this application to work properly with server-side rendering or webworkers if you do.